# Extend duration of AWS temporary security credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway, aws-sts

when calling AssumeRole, we can set the time from 900 seconds (15 minutes) to a maximum of 3600 seconds (1 hour). The default is 1 hour. Can this be more than 1 hours. like 12 hours?

Comment: The maximum is 3600 seconds. There is no document anywhere which says otherwise. I would suggest getting in touch with AWS support to check if this can be altered for your specific account.

Answer (score 5):

No the time cannot be extended above 3600 seconds (1 hour). I once tried contacting AWS support regarding the extension in time and they said no too.

Comment: thanks, I thought so. I will trying contacting AWS once more and update my findings in here. cheers.